# Two ros roots defined in config, delete one

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that I am having the same problem as defined in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/30446/error-in-rosinstall-two-ros-roots-defined-in/), and like the poster Felix, rosinstall never finishes and the setup files are not generated. Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem? The exact input and output I have is this:

`~$ rosinstall ~/ros-py3 /opt/ros/electric http://ias.cs.tum.edu/~kargm/ros_electric_py3.rosinstall</br>
rosinstall operating on /home/bakerea2/ros-py3 from specifications in rosinstall files  /opt/ros/electric, http://ias.cs.tum.edu/~kargm/ros_electric_py3.rosinstall
(Over-)Writing /home/bakerea2/ros-py3/.rosinstall</br>
[ros] Updating /home/bakerea2/ros-py3/ros</br>
[ros] Done.</br>
[ros_comm] Updating /home/bakerea2/ros-py3/ros_comm</br>
[ros_comm] Done.</br>
[common_msgs] Updating /home/bakerea2/ros-py3/common_msgs</br>
[common_msgs] Done.</br>
(Over-)Writing setup.sh, setup.bash, and setup.zsh in /home/bakerea2/ros-py3</br>
ERROR in rosinstall: Two ros roots defined in config, delete one: /opt/ros/electric/ros /home/bakerea2/ros-py3/ros</br>
~$` 

Thanks for reading.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37013/two-ros-roots-defined-in-config,-delete-one/) by [EABaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2555/eabaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to leave out the /opt/ros/electric in your rosinstall call, i.e. you need to call rosinstall like this:

```
rosinstall ~/ros-py3 http://ias.cs.tum.edu/~kargm/ros_electric_py3.rosinstall
```

When you have a look at the rosinstall file, you'll see that the first line checks out the stack `ros` which normally is the ROS_ROOT until Electric. That's why you cannot pass `/opt/ros/electric` since it provides a second (unpatched) ROS_ROOT.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1